# What is this error : IA__gdk_drawable_get_size in gvim and how can i fix this?

Tags: vim

I am using gvim and suddenly when scrolling my terminal in starts to print this message :

```
(gvim:25179): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 10:04:26.569: IA__gdk_drawable_get_size: assertion 'GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed
```

1, What does the error mean?

2, How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use Vim's issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

This is a message from the Gdk library which is part of GTK+, the windowing toolkit you're using.  Unfortunately, the GTK+ developers thought it would be a good idea to write debug messages to standard error and provide no way to disable them or otherwise turn them off, despite the fact that they clutter the terminal and are not useful except to the authors of the software.  Last I checked, they continue to maintain that position.

The GTK+ developers suggest that you file a bug with the maintainers of the package.  If you're using a distro, you should file the bug there.  My experience is that the Debian maintainers are usually quite good about addressing these things, especially for programs such as editors and browsers that are often invoked from the terminal.  Other distros may or may not be as good.

You could also try filing a bug with the Vim issue tracker, but you'll need to inform them what version of GTK+ you're using and a lot of other information so that they can figure out what's affected and how to reproduce it, especially since the error messages can come and go depending on the version of GTK+ and other libraries.